# django select_related() calls database each time object is referenced, instead of just once

Tags: python, django, django-orm

using `select_related`, each time I reference the query set, another call to the database is made. instead of caching the result.

**models.py**
    ....

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
...
```

**views.py**

```
....
photos = Photo.objects.select_related('album').filter(album_id = id).all()
chosen_album = photos[0]
print(photos)

....
```

will result in 2 different calls to the database for each reference to "photos", as verified by `manage.py runserver_plus --print-sql`

is this normal? or am I not using `select_related()` properly?

**EDIT:**

this statement in my template is what's causing the additional DB calls that I'm trying to prevent `{% for photo in photos%}`

```
...
{% for photo in photos%}
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="img-wrapper" id="{{ photo.id }}">
...
```

**EDIT 2**
Sorry I should have included this in my view.... This is the other line getting a DB call.

```
chosen_album = photos[0]
```

Since I need to get the album info...

Comment: Printing a queryset will execute a slice of the query every time returning the first 20 results. This has nothing to do the `select_related`, if you removed it you would still get all the calls to the DB

Comment: the point is that, **`print(photos.album.title)`** won't consume **`N`** db calls

Comment: @dangel Your use of `select_related` is fine. Can you share your view? You are getting a DB call every time you use `photo.album`?

Comment: sorry I meant in my template.  It's only a single extra call for   `{% for photo in photos %}`  but I was trying to reduce from 2 calls when I originally queried for `Albums` and then `Photos`

Comment: is it because I have multiple photos objects? and not just one

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is normal. You have not used the selected_related() for its intended purpose. Select_related in your case is used to load 'albums' as you load the 'photos' using the the normal **join**  sql statement. This prevents another DB hit when you call photo.album

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: so what's the best way to get both `Album` and `Photo` without a separate call to the DB, and still be able to access `photos` without subsequent DB calls?

Comment: What you are doing is right. photos = Photo.objects.select_related('album').filter(album_id = id).all() will fetch both photo and album. You are however not testing it correctly by printing photos multiple times. The test just runs your query again.

Comment: see my edit.  `{% for photo in photos %}` in my template is what I first noticed consuming the additional DB call.

Comment: No. That should not correct. Another db hit can only happen if you call photo.album.user

Comment: Sorry, I've failed to include all relevant information :-( . the other DB call was for `chosen_album = photos[0]` in my view. which I needed to get the album info.

Comment: is it because I have multiple photos objects? and not just one